# Firebase Realtime Database Setting Rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple app I am trudging through learning how to make, it only displays a list of data that I upload periodically for discounts and coupon deals. There is no user data gathered, so I don't see a need for authentication or to log in. However as I learn and read about about storing and retrieving data, it seems I might have to. Specifically when it comes to my firebase realtime database. It is telling me my rules are insecure having both read and write set to true for public. I understand the "write" being unsafe, but is there a problem with letting the "read" function be set to true for anyone if I'm not storing any personal data? Is there any way for me to say "anyone can read, but only I can write, but I don't want everyone to have to create usernames and passwords" or is that illogical thinking and I should just make a login screen? Thank you for any insight.

Edit: I currently put my coupon data into the database via a short standalone javascript program I wrote that takes a csv file I write and writes it to the database. If I change write to false for all, I'm afraid that will prevent my program from writing. So I guess in order to keep using my program to write the data I'd have to have SOME kind of authentication, right? Very good to know I can leave the read to true for the public, thank you.

```
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "deals": {
      ".indexOn": ["indexStore", "promoCode"]
    },
  }
```

Comment: There is no issue with allowing everyone to read unless you would like only users of your app to be able to read the coupon data.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes! Here is how you can do it:**

Just change the `".write": true` to `".write": false`. That will do it

Comment: Thank you, currently how I get my coupon data in there is I have a standalone short javascript program that takes a csv file I create, and it writes it to my database. If I change the write function to false for all, will that not prevent my program from writing to it? I probably should have included that in my post. I will edit. Thank you again.